# When using HAML, is there a way to use heredoc or %Q{ ... }?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Maybe it can be put into a helper but the existing 500 lines of code has everything in the HAML code, so it is better to follow the existing code for the moment (for tight deadlines).

I found the only way working right now is

```
- meta_tag = %Q{\n |
  <meta ...>\n |
  <meta ...>\n |
    [...]   \n |
  } |
```

which is to use the "continuation character" and the `\n` at the same time.  It'd be great if it can be simplified.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to do this would be to use the [`:ruby filter`](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#ruby-filter) or load the needed content into a Ruby variable and pass it into HAML the normal way.

Comment: Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: Example of which? Both are documented in the HAML documentation.

Comment: Docs on filters is very succinct and provides no examples, none with a heredoc whatsoever. I'm having a hard time trying to assign a heredoc string to a variable, getting indentation and parsing errors, that's why I ask. BTW, docs new link is http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby-filter

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what "the Tin Man" meant.

```
:ruby                                                                                                                                                                                        
  text =<<-EOT                                                                                                                                                                               
  Hi,                                                                                                                                                                                        
    Please find some heredoc text                                                                                                                                                            
      right here                                                                                                                                                                             

  Bye                                                                                                                                                                                        
  EOT                                                                                                                                                                                        

%pre=text
```

I could not add this as a comment to his post, sorry!