# Pass ruby block to partial in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, haml, partial-views

I have made a partial for generating some of the layout of my page, and I have in the partial a space where I would need to insert a description.

The description is static text from the caller of the partial, and it's pretty long. so I would like to write it as a block of text.

This is what I have:

```
= render "feature", title: "Planning", text: <<-BLOCK
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
BLOCK
```

but when I try rendering the page I get:

```
can't find string "BLOCK" anywhere before EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use a `yield` and provide the content in a `content_for` block.

In your partial:

```
%p Other content wrapping the block of text
= yield :text_block
%p Other content wrapping the block of text
```

Then in your view:

```
= content_for :text_block do
  The content you need to insert goes here ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this might work, though I need to call the partial several times with different text, and `content_for` seems to be incremental, If I use it twice, the second time I print its content it will have the first and the second text concatenated.

I've tried using `flush: true` too, but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Using `content_for` for multiple partials will not work. Instead you could try passing the content as part of the `locals` argument?

Comment: I've tried that, but to make it work I had to give the content_for different names, each time, and then use the `test: content_for :name` 

not too neat but this works.

Comment: @dongiulio My answer proffers the HAML filter `:ruby`—you wouldn't have to vary the content_for names when rendering multiple partials in a view…

Answer (score 1):

This Rails code passes a "block"/heredoc to a partial within a HAML view:

```
- Haml::Template.options[:suppress_eval] = false
:ruby
  haml_io.puts render "feature", title: "Planning", text: <<BLOCK
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  BLOCK
```

*(using HAML 4.0.5 and Rails 3.2.13)*

- http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby-filter
- [Output haml content via :ruby filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328758/output-haml-content-via-ruby-filter)
- [When using HAML, is there a way to use heredoc or %Q{ ... }?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910593/when-using-haml-is-there-a-way-to-use-heredoc-or-q)
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here%5Fdoc